# Add to cart functionality like zopnow app

Tags: objective-c, json, sqlite, cart

I try to implement add to cart like zopnow app.
Anyone know concept behind add to cart like zopnow app.its really good functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The process behind the magic sync cart on [zopnow.com](https://www.zopnow.com)  is as follows:

- Whenever a user adds or removes an item to/from the cart, it is updated on the server in background so that the user can continue to browse the app seamlessly.
- The server intelligently merges requests from all devices (where the user is logged in) to magically sync the cart across all devices

PS: I'm the dev lead for the [iOS App](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/zopnow-online-grocery-shopping/id638117645?mt=8)